# Reconstructing file structure in ZIP file from list of strings

Tags: gradle, zip

This is probably a lot easier than I am making it. I have a string list of files, with their relative locations, in the current project, dynamically generated, which we want to add to a zip file. I currently have the following code:

```
task sourceDrop(type: Zip) {
    def filelist = getFileList()
    
    baseName = "sourceDrop"
    version = "1.0"
    filelist.each {
        from it // adds every single file to the archive
    }
    destinationDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "")
}
```

It's creating a zip file with every item in it as a flat structure, no folders. Is there an elegant way to say "keep the relative paths"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_gradle/tree/master/egg_StackOverflow_64936976).

Consider this task:

```
task sourceDrop(type: Zip) {
    def filelist = getFileList() 
 
    baseName = "sourceDrop"
    version = "1.0"
    
    fileList.each { file ->
        def info = getFileInfo(file)
        from (info.relativeDir) {
            include info.filename into info.relativeDir
        }
    }

    destinationDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "")
}
```

Note that `getFileInfo()` is a home-grown method that splits a relative path into the path and file name.

Comment: Thank you. The only modification I had to make was handling some files that lacked a path, as the list had relative paths and some were in the base directory.

Answer (score 1):

you need add the to path inside the zip (pseudo code)

```
filelist.each {
    from it // adds every single file to the archive
    into it.substring(it.lastIndexOf("/"))
}
```